# Chrome not displaying fixed navigation on website - both Mac & PC

Tags: image, google-chrome

When viewing this site: http://jonimi.com in Chrome on both Mac & PC - the top area (a fixed navigation bar) is not visible. I haven't really been able to find anything as to why this is happening. It works on all other browsers except Chrome. Help is greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of

```
#header_wrapper
{position: fixed;}
```